# Attempting to add QLayout "" to convertidorNumericoDialogo "" which already has a layout

Tags: c++, regex, qt, layout, qt-creator

Hola que tal tengo el problema mencionado en el titulo, el programa consta de 3 QLineEdit en donde en el primero se introduce un numero decimal, en el segundo un hexadecimal y en el 3ero un binario.
tengo señales para que cuando se introduzca un decimal, se ponga en el hexadecimal su respectivo valor convertido del decimal, y así con el binario.

hasta ahí antes funcionaba, coloqué después para que al meter un binario o hexadecimal, se convierta a decimal , y al otro valor correspondiente.

pido su ayuda, capaz que no estoy viendo algo.... es la primera vez que utilizo los QGridLayout, etc etc.

#### mi código es el siguiente:

### codigo de convertidorNumerico.cpp

```c
#include "convertidornumerico.h"

convertidorNumerico::convertidorNumerico(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void convertidorNumerico::setDec(const QString &cadena)
{
    bool ok;
    int num = cadena.toInt(&ok);
    if ( ok )
    {
        emit hexChanged(QString::number(num, 16));
        emit binChanged(QString::number(num, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        emit hexChanged("");
        emit binChanged("");
    }
}

void convertidorNumerico::setHex(const QString &cadena)
{
    bool ok;
    int num = cadena.toInt(&ok, 16);
    if ( ok )
    {
        emit decChanged(QString::number(num));
        emit binChanged(QString::number(num, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        emit decChanged("");
        emit binChanged("");
    }
}

void convertidorNumerico::setBin(const QString &cadena)
{
    bool ok;
    int num = cadena.toInt(&ok);
    if ( ok )
    {
        emit decChanged(QString::number(num));
        emit hexChanged(QString::number(num, 16));
    }
    else
    {
        emit decChanged("");
        emit hexChanged("");
    }
}
```

### codigo de convertidorNumerico.h

```c
#ifndef CONVERTIDORNUMERICO_H
#define CONVERTIDORNUMERICO_H

#include <QObject>

class convertidorNumerico : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit convertidorNumerico( QObject *parent = nullptr );

signals:
    void decChanged(const QString &);
    void hexChanged(const QString &);
    void binChanged(const QString &);

public slots:
    void setDec(const QString &);
    void setHex(const QString &);
    void setBin(const QString &);
};

#endif // CONVERTIDORNUMERICO_H
```

### codigo de convertidorNumericoDialogo.cpp

```c
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QRegularExpressionValidator>

#include "convertidornumericodialogo.h"
#include "convertidornumerico.h"

/*convertidorNumericoDialogo::convertidorNumericoDialogo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}*/

convertidorNumericoDialogo::convertidorNumericoDialogo()
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout   ( this );
    QGridLayout *editLayout = new QGridLayout   ( this );
    QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout    ( this );

    QLabel *decLabel = new QLabel("decimal");
    QLabel *hexLabel = new QLabel("Hexadecimal");
    QLabel *binLabel = new QLabel("Binario");

    decEdit = new QLineEdit;
    hexEdit = new QLineEdit;
    binEdit = new QLineEdit;

    editLayout->addWidget(decLabel, 0, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget( decEdit, 0, 1 );
    editLayout->addWidget( hexLabel, 1, 0 );
    editLayout->addWidget( hexEdit, 1, 1 );

    editLayout->addWidget(binLabel, 2, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget(binEdit, 2, 1);

    QPushButton *btnSalir = new QPushButton("SALIR");
    btnLayout->addStretch();
    btnLayout->addWidget(btnSalir);

    mainLayout->addLayout(editLayout);
    mainLayout->addStretch();
    mainLayout->addLayout(btnLayout);

    btnSalir->setDefault(true);
    connect(btnSalir, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(accept()));

    // VALORES DE UN BYTE : 0 - 255
    QIntValidator *decVal = new QIntValidator(0, 255, decEdit);
    decEdit->setValidator(decVal);

    // EXP REG PARA VALIDAR HEXADECIMALES DE HASTA 2 DIGITOS....
    QRegularExpressionValidator *hexVal = new QRegularExpressionValidator(
                QRegularExpression("^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}"), hexEdit);
    hexEdit->setValidator(hexVal);

    // EXP REG PARA VALIDAR BINARIOS DE HASTA 8 BYTES....
    QRegularExpressionValidator *binVal = new QRegularExpressionValidator(
                QRegularExpression("[0-1]{1,8}"), binEdit);
    binEdit->setValidator(binVal);

    convertidorNumerico *convertidor = new convertidorNumerico;

    connect(decEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setDec(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(hexChanged(QString)), hexEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(binChanged(QString)), binEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));


    // tarea: => CONECTAR las señales de hexa y binario, para que ingresando esos datos, se devuelva la info en la app.
    connect(hexEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setHex(QString)));
    connect(binEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setBin(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(decChanged(QString)), decEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
}
```

### codigo del convertidorNumericoDialogo.h

```c
#ifndef CONVERTIDORNUMERICODIALOGO_H
#define CONVERTIDORNUMERICODIALOGO_H

#include <QDialog>


class QLineEdit;
class convertidorNumericoDialogo : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //explicit convertidorNumericoDialogo(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit convertidorNumericoDialogo();

private:
    QLineEdit *decEdit;
    QLineEdit *hexEdit;
    QLineEdit *binEdit;

};

#endif // CONVERTIDORNUMERICODIALOGO_H
```

alguna solución? ya probé de todo y no lo hago funcionar...

Answer (score 0):

<s>Acabo de construir un proyecto con tu código y me funciona perfectamente. Prueba a volver a construirlo con `qmake` (Build-->Run qmake) y luego a `Rebuild`.</s>

Por si acaso, este sería el main.cpp (que supongo que lo tienes igual):

```
#include "convertidornumericodialogo.h"    
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);    
    convertidorNumericoDialogo c;
    c.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Edito la respuesta:**

1.- El primer problema, el que da el título a la pregunta, es debido a estas líneas:

```
QGridLayout *editLayout = new QGridLayout   ( this );
QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout    ( this );
```

En las cuales pones a estos dos elementos como hijos de la instancia del QObject `ConvertidorNumericoDialogo`,pero luego haces esto:

```
mainLayout->addLayout(editLayout);
mainLayout->addLayout(btnLayout)
```

Con el método `addLayout` le pones a estos layouts como hijos del `mainLayout`, cuando ya tenían como padre el widget principal. Por esto el mensaje.

La solución es crear los elementos sin asignarles como padre el objeto actual:

```
QGridLayout *editLayout = new QGridLayout;
QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
```

Respecto a la lógica, el problema es que cada vez que cambiabas el contenido de cualquier QLineEdit, se cambiaba en el resto de QLineEdit, pero al emitir la señal, se volvían a cambiar entrando en un bucle.
Para solucionarlo, mejor usar una señal que no se emite cuando el texto se cambia de forma programática, sino sólo cuando se actúa de forma directa sobre el QLineEdit. Esta señal es [textEdited(const QString &text)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited)

This signal is emitted whenever the text is edited. The text argument is the new text.

> Unlike textChanged(), this signal is not emitted when the text is
> changed programmatically, for example, by calling setText().

En resumen, estas son las únicas señales que debería tener la clase `convertidorNumericoDialogo`:

```
connect(decEdit, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setDec(QString)));
    connect(hexEdit, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setHex(QString)));
    connect(binEdit, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setBin(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(hexChanged(QString)), hexEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(binChanged(QString)), binEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(decChanged(QString)), decEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
```

Comment: mi codigo en main tiene una linea mas que la tuya y esa es: cNum.setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose); cNum es lo que tu tienes como c, pero voy a tratar como tu me comentas haber si funciona.

Comment: sigue igual, cuando escribo algo en los QLineEdit se vuelve loco y pone datos que yo no puse.... y me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje ...

Comment: Ah. Disculpa. Pensaba que el programa no te compilaba por algún error en el diseño de la interfaz gráfica. La verdad es que tampoco miré si el comportamiento del programa era correcto. Me pareció que sí, porque cualquier número que ponía en el edit binario me lo convertía de forma automática, pero no hice más averiguaciones.

Comment: si, me pone numeros cualesquiera, pero no me deja poner el que yo quiero,es decir, cuando quiero escribir 15, y pongo un 1 , en lugar de eso, se pone por si solo un 110134778 que yo no quería poner... está raro eso....

Comment: He editado la respuesta.